# In Ruby how are collections defined?

Tags: ruby, collections

I read a lot about collections in Ruby. How are they defined? There isn't a Ruby `Collection` page in the Ruby documentation. I know, for instance, that `Array` is a collection, [as the Docs say it is an ordered, integer-indexed collections of any object.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html) Is it simply something that includes the `Enumerable` mixin?

There's no `kind_of?(Collection)`?

```
[1] > my_array.class
=> Array
[2] > my_array.kind_of?(Array)
=> true
[3] > my_array.kind_of?(Collection)
     NameError: uninitialized constant <something or other>::Collection
[4] > my_array.kind_of?(Enumerable)
=> true
```

I'm asking because Rails talks a lot about collections so I thought I better know for sure what it is.

Comment: _“Collection”_ here stands for a common term, not ruby keyword/class.

Comment: Thanks mudasobwa, I added in your comment to the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Collection” in Ruby stands for a common term, there's no `Collection` class or keyword in the core library.

Speaking of Rails, a *collection* usually means something enumerable, but there are no explicit checks for `kind_of?(Enumerable)` in Rails code, either. It's could be a nicer way to say `Enumerable`, or maybe it's just sloppy and confusing documentation, or a consequense of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Go figure.

You might think that `Enumerable` is a [protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_%28object-oriented_programming%29), but it's not - it's just a collection of helper methods build around `each`.

Comment: False. There is explicit check if object is `Enumerable`:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-kind_of-3F

Comment: @MarekLipka what I meant is, Rails does not check it, not that it's impossible.

Comment: However, the `Enumerable` *mixin* depends on a protocol … one might call it `Eachable` to avoid confusion.